# Close with timeout is not working in Console to close splashscreen

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, console-application, instance

I have made a class, I make an instance of. In said instance I have these lines of code to show and close the splashscreen.

```
// Open (show)
public void ShowSplashScreen(bool autoClose = false)
{
    splashscreen.Show(autoClose, true);
}

// Close (don't show)
public void CloseSplashScreen()
{
    splashscreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
}
```

It shows up fine, but never closes, just stays there.

This is the documentation of splashscreen Close: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen.close?view=netframework-4.8

> [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
>
> public void Close (TimeSpan fadeoutDuration);

Note: I am using the `show` method with the parameters `AutoClose` set to `false`, and `TopMost` set to `true`, this makes it not auto close as I want to close it programmatically and not subscribe to existing events.

---

I am running the lines of code from a Console (.NET framework) application for testing purposes before implementing it into my UI fully.

---

What I have tried:
Debugging and even trying to call `show` again before calling `close`.

---

It is definitely something going wrong with the class, as calling the class and directly manipulating the property works:

```
ClassSplashScreen rss = new ClassSplashScreen();
rss.splashscreen.Show(false);
rss.splashscreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

My best guess is something is hanging the UI and freezing it? But I am unsure what to do about it.

---

Code to run to test this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace NamespaceName
{
    public class StackOverFlowCode
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassSplashScreen screen = new ClassSplashScreen();
            screen.ShowSplashScreen();
            screen.CloseSplashScreen();
        }

    }
    public class ClassSplashScreen
    {
        public SplashScreen splashscreen { get; set; }
        public ClassSplashScreen()
        {
            splashscreen = new SplashScreen("Resource Image Link");
        }
        public void ChangeSplashResource(SplashScreen resource)
        {
            splashscreen = resource;
        }
        public void ShowSplashScreen(bool autoClose = false)
        {
            splashscreen.Show(autoClose, true);
        }
        public void CloseSplashScreen()
        {
            splashscreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It the "CloseSplashScreen" methode ever called?

Comment: @Luc Yes, I have debugged and ensured that it is called and passes through with no exceptions.

Comment: A console? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue when asking a question.

Comment: @mm8 the code I have provided should be exactly that, all I do except that is call the methods in a console application (.net framework)


Like this:

`ShowSplashScreen()

CloseSplashScreen()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SplashScreen` relies on a dispatcher but there is no one in a console application by default. If you create a `System.Windows.Application`, it should work as expected:

```
public class StackOverFlowCode
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.Startup += (s, e) => 
        {
            ClassSplashScreen screen = new ClassSplashScreen();
            screen.ShowSplashScreen();
            screen.CloseSplashScreen();
        };
        app.Run();
    }
}

public class ClassSplashScreen
{
    private readonly SplashScreen splashscreen;

    public ClassSplashScreen() => splashscreen = new SplashScreen("Resource Image Link");

    public void ShowSplashScreen() => splashscreen.Show(false);

    public void CloseSplashScreen() => splashscreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```